# Unit Testing Highly Dependent (Network Dependent) Functions in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit tests for a project that I am working on (written in C++ with Qt), but I'm having difficulty since my code largely depends on network responses.  My project contains one main class with three important functions.  The workflow looks something like this:

```
// myclass.h
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
class MyClass
{
    void function1();
    void function2();
    void function3();
    QNetworkAccessManager manager; // this is the object used to make network requests
}

// myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
MyClass::function1()
{
    // this function should be called to start the chain of events

    // set up the first request
    manager.get("www.myserver.com");
}

MyClass::function2()
{
    // this function is called with the response of the request made in function1

    // process the results of the first request
    // set up the second request
    manager.get("www.yourserver.com");
}

MyClass::function3()
{
    // this function is called with the results of the second request

    // process the results of the second request
}
```

I've left out most of the nitty gritty details for clarity, but the code above is a good illustration of how the class is organized.  There is one function within the class that should be called to start the process, and the other functions are called when the network requests finish so that the results of those requests can be processed.

I would like to test each function individually so that I can throw in a lot of different responses and different error situations, to make sure that my code reacts properly in each situation.  The problem is that I don't need or want my functions to actually make any internet requests during these tests.  I've searched online, but haven't found any really good solutions.  Here are the options that I've found:

1. Linker Tricks

   - The idea here is to create a mock class that is also named QNetworkAccessReply, with a dummy `get` function that doesn't actually make any network requests.  Then during compile time I link my code to this mock class instead of the one that ships with Qt.
   - This idea seems to be the cleanest that I've found as far as not needing to modi my class, but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually pull this off in practice.
2. Preprocessor Directives

   - This idea involves creating a mock object, let's say `QNetworkAccessManager_Mock`, and defining a macro in one of my test files, something like: `#define TESTCASE`.  Then within the code that I am trying the test, I would replace an instance of `QNetworkAccessManager manager;` with:

     ```
     #ifdef TESTCASE
         QNetworkAccessManager_Mock manager;
     #else
         QNetworkAccessManager manager;
     #endif
     ```
   - This option is relatively easy to implement in small projects, but can get unruly in larger projects where your code would have to be riddled with `#ifdef` sections.  I don't like the level of modification to my original code that this option involves
3. Edit my source files with a script

   - I could create a simple script that runs through my source files to replace each instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` with a mock class instead.
   - This option allows me to leave my source code untouched, and I don't have to mess with linking properly at compile time, but it seems like a lot of extra overhead that shouldn't be needed.
4. Modify the destination url for each request

   - I could choose a url for a local server that I know doesn't exist, such as `localhost:9000`.  In this case, each network request would fail in a predictable way, but it seems like too much of a hack just to get it to work.
   - Alternatively, my unit tests could spin up a local server from which I could return some canned responses.  This seems to me like too much overhead just to check how each individual function responds, and it still doesn't let me check how my class responds to errors having to deal with network failures.
   - In either case, I would still need a way to modify the url, either using preprocessor directives, bringing me back to the issues with #2 and #3.
5. Just don't write tests.

   - This option defeats the whole purpose

There are plenty of examples that exist for mocking dependencies **if I was the one that wrote the dependent classes**.  There doesn't seem to be any clean and easy solutions, however, for mocking dependent classes that exist within other libraries.  Are the solutions that I outlined above really my only options, or have I overlooked something?  What would you recommend as my best choice?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C++, but have you looked into the existing C++ mocking libraries? Python's mock library lets you create mock classes around arbitrary classes, including 3rd party libraries. I'm not sure if C++ is as permissive, but I'd imagine people will try to do so as much as possible.

Googling C++ mock gave me https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/

Comment: I looked at Google Mock, but couldn't find good examples of how to mock existing 3rd party libraries.  I'll give it another look to see if I missed something...

Comment: As for the fourth option, if you're always going to be running the unit tests on the same machine you could easily redirect the URLs using a [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) on that machine.

Comment: Disclaimer I work at Typemock: Typemock Isolator++ mocks third party libraries, non virtual methods, statics... you don't have to alter your code just for testing. Come check it at http://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best solution just in use c++ class aggregation. You can create Helper class such as this:

```
class Helper
{
    void function1();
    void function2();
    void function3();
}
```

And agregate this class in MyClass. MyClass.h:

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include "Helper.h"
class MyClass
{
    void function1();
    void function2();
    void function3();
    Helper helper;
    QNetworkAccessManager manager; // this is the object used to make network requests
}
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "myclass.h"
MyClass::function1()
{
    helper.function1();
    manager.get("www.myserver.com");
}

MyClass::function2()
{
    helper.function2();
    manager.get("www.yourserver.com");
}

MyClass::function3()
{
    helper.function3();
}
```

In this case you need to test Helper class.

Comment: In my case, I was able to just put the helper functions in "MyClass."  Nevertheless, it was the same concept and it worked beautifully!  It seems like such an obvious solution in retrospect... Thanks!